# Replace an N-channel MOSFET with equivalent in chinese solar inverter

Tags: powermosfet

I am planning to replace the NCEP85T16 MOSFET in a Easun SV IV hybrid inverter. The blown out MOSFETs are on the 48 V battery DC boost side of the inverter.
I found a possible replacement in Toshibas TK2R9E10PL easily found on local market.
Datasheets are here:
For NCEP85T16
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2004201608_Wuxi-NCE-Power-Semiconductor-NCEP85T16_C503003.pdf

For TK2R9E10PL
https://ro.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/TK2R9E10PL_datasheet_en_20210202-2509666.pdf

For the TK2R9E10PL will be a improvement. It has lower rds-on, higher breakdown voltage, higher current. But, according to the datasheet, it has higher input capacitance (9500 pF vs 8500 pF) and higher gate charge (161 nC vs 105 nC).

MOSFET driver is NSi6602
https://www.szhaina.com/uploads/media/20220417/1650184782.pdf

I wonder if the TK2R9E10PL can be a good replacement of the NCEP85T16?

Comment: Why did they fail?

Comment: _”easily found on local market”_ Why limit yourself? Digikey, Mouser, RS and Farnell ships all over the world. Can you trace out a schematic around the failed MOSFET? Are there MOSFETs connected in parallel?

Comment: Note that when FETs fail, they often take out the driver and possibly other circuitry as well.  So unless you're lucky just replacing the MOSFETs won't fix the problem.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 they failed due of bad wiring on the inverter (2 inverters to put in parallel mode with PV section linked togeter).

Comment: @winny I found equivalent FMOSETs on mouser. Unfortunatelly I cannot find original NCEP85T16 on Mouser, Farnell, Digikey. Only on Ali Express and I cannot wait too long for them. The MOSFETS are conected in parallel ( 8 by 8 in half bidge ).

Comment: @JohnD I didn`t found other bad components so far. I will continue investigating further.

Comment: No worries. From the schematic you’ll trace out we can probably tell you where there is wiggle room for the specs of the replacement compared to original MOSFET.

Comment: There is a special parallel PCB option for tandem current sharing. Higher C is normal with lower RdsOn. Hopefully it will run cool.

Answer (score 1):

The driver seems liable to be capable enough.

Gate capacitances are essentially identical.
Gate charge should be handled OK by the driver. No guarantees though :-).

Note that thermal Rjc is also important - and Toshiba is better.

Toshiba note in the datasheet says that there is a 100A  Ids limit due to package. Ncepower doesn't BUT Toshiba should be (should) superior regardless.